# Java applet warning on JRE 1.7u45

Tags: java, applet

I have written a simple test applet and it throws me following warning on JRE 1.7u45
"Running unsigned applications like these will be blocked in future because it is potentially unsafe and a security risk"

Applet is :

```
   <html>
   <applet height="60" alt="Browser has Java disabled" hspace="22" width="440"     
    code="Hello.class">
    </applet>
    </html>
```

The applet just prints out Hello world.

I understand that with JRE 1.7u51, Java will blocked RIA's that are unsigned. My question is regarding applets like above that do not have a archive and codebase attribute. (I know it is recommended to put Hello.class in archive file). But will an applet like this be treated unsigned and blocked in JRE 1.7u51?

Answer (score 1):

> But will an applet like this be treated unsigned and blocked in JRE 1.7u51?

It sure will.  An unjarred applet *cannot* be signed, and will therefore suffer the full force of the new security regime.